# Is that true that $\|g\circ f\|\leq \|g\|\cdot\|f\|$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I have to construct an argument to my proof and I want to use a result that I don't know if it's true. The question is:

Let $f\in\mathcal{L}(E,F)$ and $g\in\mathcal{L}(F,G)$. Is that true that $\|g\circ f\|\leq \|g\|\cdot\|f\|$?

My attempt was:
As $g$ is continuous, then there is a $C>0$ such that $\|g(y)\|\leq C\|y\|$, for all $y\in F$.
So:
$$\|g(f(x))\|\leq C\|f(x)\|.$$
And we can see here that $\|g\circ f\|\leq C\|f\|$.
But how is going to appear $\|g\|$?
I think this is true, but i can't get there.

If it's true (as I imagine), so how can I visualize an example (non-trivial, ie, not the equality) that shows it happening? Like... $\|g\circ f\|<\|g\|\cdot \|f\|$?

Comment: Try $C:=\|g\|$.

Comment: @daw man.... $C$ is not arbitrary.

Comment: @Manatee No it is not, but if $g$ is a bounded operator (which is an assumption you made in your post), then taking $C = ||g||$ works by definition.

Comment: Note that linearity of $g$ is essential else $f=0$ would be a trivial counterexample. We have $g(0)=0$ for linear applications.

Comment: @zwim yeah, you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the definition of norm operaror and how that translates to continuity (in the finite-dimensial case that happens always). Can you see why
$$ \|g(z)||\leq ||g||||z|| ?$$
Now choose $z$ wisely and use the same argument.

Comment: (You should also conclude by taking into account that what you have proved, for $z=f(x)$ and $x$ *unitary* is what you were looking for.)

Comment: So $||g(f(x))||\leq ||g||||f||||x||$?
But what does ||g|| and ||f|| mean in this case? They are not applied in an element.

Comment: The operator norm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm, you used it on your question.

Comment: Do you see it? It proves it, just a matter of applying the definition twice.

Comment: So-so, is the operator's norm given by the $\inf$?

Comment: You shound rather look at the $sup$ definition (which is equivalent and more intuitive)

Comment: Can you explain a little more, please?

Comment: If we define $||T||=sup\{Tx : ||x||=1\}$ then, for all $x\neq 0$ in the space, taking $z=x/||x||$ we would have $||Tz||\leq||T||$ and from this it follows that $||Tx|| \leq ||T||||x||$

Comment: And thus is you do what I've mentioned above for non-zero vectors there is a bound for the operator norm ||f o g||  "$sup$ is smaller".

Comment: I got it, but I can't understand why $||(gf)(x))|| \leq (||g||||f||)||x||$ shows that $$||g\circ f||\leq ||g||\cdot ||f||.$$
It's not clear the "x" inside de norm and the "x" out of the norm conclude it.

Comment: Take all unitary "x" and as I have said you have found an upper bound for the norm. Thus the norm of the composition is less or equal to the product of the norms.

Comment: I finally got it! Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: I still can't see it in an example. Do you know any? $||g\circ f||<||g||||f||$. I can visualize if they are equal, but not strict.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132363/discussion-between-sultandegranada-and-manatee).

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align} \|(gf)(x))\|=\|g(f(x)\|&\leq \|g\|\|f(x)\|\\&\le\|g\|\|f\|\|x\|\\&=(\|g\|\|f\|)\|x\|\end{align}

Now apply definition of norm of $\|gf\|$.